# AD test in R Interpretation

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I am very new to statistics, so was wondering if i could get any help in understanding AD test in R. My question is how to interpret AD test results from R. if i run AD test with 2 or 3 random sample data set in R, i get an result.. how do i decide what value to use between AD and T.AD? and version 1 or version 2? And why do i get negative values in AD/ T.AD or greater than 1 values in AD/ T.AD?

Using KSamples package

Example:

Code:

```
x<-runif(50,1,100)
y<-runif(50,1,100)
z<-runif(50,1,100)
ad1<-ad.test(x,y,z)

Output:
         AD    T.AD  asym P value
version1 0.74  -1.18  0.96
version2 0.73   -1.19  0.96

Which value id correct? AD or T.AD? and why is T.AD -ve?
```

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: @Edward I am using KSamples

Comment: I just figured that out. I asked because there are at least two other packages with a function of the same name. Anyway, T.AD is the standardized Anderson-Darling test statistic, calculated in the usual way: `(AD - μ)/σ`. If you read the help page for this function, you should get all the answers you're after. :)

Comment: Oh, I may as well copy and paste it here: According to the reference article, two versions of the AD test statistic are provided. The above mean and standard deviation are strictly valid only for version 1 in the continuous distribution case.

Comment: @Edward I am more confused as to why T.AD values are coming negative.. what does it mean and why is AD value positive? What does negative signify?

Comment: Don't be confused about a negative T.AD value. It's a standardized AD test statistic. Do you know what that means? It means negative values are equally likely as positive ones. A negative value means that the mean is larger than the unstandardized AD test statistic, which is always positive since the value is calculated by summation or integration. If you really want more details, read the references given at the end of the help page. :)